# work with image: imgcompare does not support list?

Tags: python, list, image-comparison

`import imgcompare`
...

```
for filename in os.listdir(myPath):
     if filename.endswith(".png"):
         listIm1.append(filename)

for filename2 in os.listdir(myPath2):
     if filename2.endswith(".png"):
         listIm2.append(filename2)
```

so i fill my two lists with images,now I would like to compare the images of the two lists one by one following the same index, for example:
listIm1[0] with listImg2[0]
listIm1[1] with listImg2[1]
and so on... and that's the code:

```
for item in listIm1:
        ifSame = imgcompare.is_equal(listIm1[item],listIm2[item],tolerance=2)
        print ifSame
```

but get the error:

```
same = imgcompare.is_equal(listIm1[item], listIm2[item], tolerance=2)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

> it seems that imgcompare.is_equal() does not work with lists, is there some pythonic expedient to make it
>   works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since

```
 if filename2.endswith(".png"):
         listIm2.append(filename2)

for item in listIm1:
        # item = "someimagine.png"
 ifSame = imgcompare.is_equal(listIm1[item],listIm2[item],tolerance=2)
        #listIm1[someimagine.png] is what you are asking => retrun Type Error
```

I guess you are looking for something like this:

**edit:**

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(myPath):
    if filename2.endswith(".png"):
       img_path = os.path.join(myPath,filename2)  
       listIm2.append(img_path)

listIm1 = [] 
listIm2 = []
for i in range(len(listIm1)):

     ifSame = imgcompare.is_equal(listIm1[i],listIm2[i],tolerance=2)
     print ifSame
```

and it's better if len(listIm1) == len(listIm2)

Comment: same error as above: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.png'`but with `for i in range(len(listIm1)): print listIm1[i]` file is found.

Comment: I got it, first you have to declare your list in order to append images to them, using `listIm1 = []` and `listIm1 = []`, I have updated the answer

Comment: Done, but got the same error `No such file or directory: 'image.png'` even if the file still exists.

Comment: ok, now you might need to declare the full path if the images are not in the same directory, somethings like `import os` `os.path.join("your path directory",listIm1[i])` if you print you'll get"c:\yourpath\image.png" and it should work, I've edit the anwser above

Comment: I was missing a basic instruction **os.chdir(mypath)**, so your is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to get the index of `listIm1` by using `item`. What you want to do is use a `range()`, like:

```
for i in range(len(listIm1)):
            ifSame = imgcompare.is_equal(listIm1[i],listIm2[i],tolerance=2)
```

As @Matt pointed out, this will only work if you know the lists are the same length beforehand, otherwise it will throw an index error.

Comment: Careful! This assumes that listIm1 and listIm2 are the same length!

Comment: Yep, that's right. Will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @colin with your code have error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.png'`. But with `for i in range(len(listIm1)): print listIm1[i]`have: image.png, image2.png,...

Comment: imgcompare is trying to find a file named 'image.png'. If you are getting that error, that means that there isn't a file named image.png in your current directory. When you are appending to your lists, try using 
`listIm1.append(os.path.abspath(filename))` and `listIm2.append(os.path.abspath(filename))` instead

Comment: It's quite large, a specific section?

Comment: `listIm1.append(os.path.abspath(filename))` unfortunately the same error but with the full path: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\a\\Documents\\PycharmProjects\\arduino\\image.png'`

Comment: What is `myPath` and `myPath2`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a for each loop, which grabs each element in your provided list `listIm1` and stores it in a temp variable `item`, you then pass `item` (which is a string) as an index both of your lists. Indices of a list must be an integer, and that is the error you are getting.

```
for dir1_file in listIm1:
    for dir2_file in listIm2:
        ifSame = imgcompare.is_equal(dir1_file,dir2_file,tolerance=2)
        print ifSame
```

This code uses two for each loops, it looks at each  element in both of the lists and uses them as the arguments for your method.

Comment: I would like to compare images in two lists with same index, this compare the first index of first list with all index of second list and so on, right?

Comment: You are correct. This will compare every file in dir1 with every file in dir2.  If you want to compare two lists using the same index, I would suggest using the answer provided by @colin. You just have to be sure that your two lists are going to be the same size, and be in the order you want.

Comment: I tried to use colin's answer but got an error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.png'` even if the file exists.